# Modify data in mongoose pre-validate hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to modify a document field's data prior to it being validated by mongoose, like so:

```
mySchema.pre("validate", function (next) {
  this.myField = "yay a new value prior to validation" // doesn't work for me

  next();
});
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me. The example above is simplified, in my project I'm trying to prevent an *ObjectParameterError* from crashing my server, and assigning values in my pre-validate hook doesn't work for me.

Comment: Add the code where you are trying to save a document.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.set()` method of mongoose `Document` to access value. Your code should be changed this way

```js
mySchema.pre("validate", function (next) {
  this.set("myField", "yay a new value prior to validation")
  next();
});
```